# What did I agree to in this Non-Compete/Non-Solicitation?

Tags: employment, non-compete

What did I agree to in my job offer agreement? I'm currently looking at jobs within the same business sector as my current employer's Client, but not looking for direct employment with the Client. Would anything in this agreement preclude me from getting a new job?

[image: Part of the Offer and Agreement, signed when I first started working for my employer.]

Comment: The question is really not what the clause says, which is plain English, but rather what action you are contemplating, and we can't advise you on that for both reasons.

Answer (score 1):

The second paragraph asks you to state a legal opinion about the first paragraph. Unless you are a lawyer, you are not qualified to give such a legal opinion, so this paragraph counts for nothing.

That's why companies that want to make something bullet proof will pay you to hire an employment lawyer to check the contract and advise you. Which means if the contract will cause you problems, the lawyer will tell you. If the lawyer doesn't tell you, then they are insured and their insurance will be damage caused by bad advise.

That lawyer would probably find "activity [] could be construed as competition" not acceptable. I would find it unacceptable.